# Google OAuth service redirects to URL with a # sign at the end

Tags: php, url, oauth, google-oauth, fragment-identifier

When the user is redirected to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[clientid]&redirect_uri=http://example.com/googleauth&scope=email` by our "Sign In with Google" button, the response's `Location` header that causes the redirection back to the site has a `#` symbol at the end:

> Response headers:
> location: http://example.com/googleauth?code=[code]#

It certainly does not break the site's funcionality, but I'd like to get rid of it anyway. Is there something wrong with my initial request URL, or do I need to resort to a JavaScript based solution on my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your redirect URL or client side code. This is something that Google recently added but should be of no concern to you, see also: [Google OAuth code appends extra "#" in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903316/google-oauth-code-appends-extra-in-response) and [# added to Google+ OAuth 2.0 callback URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010046/added-to-google-oauth-2-0-callback-url)

Comment: Well, it's not an issue on our end then. I guess I'll need to do some JS magic to get rid of it.

Comment: the user agent should not send the # to the backend in the first place; if it does, that user agent is in fact broken according to the HTTP spec